# Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException Can't write image data to path

Tags: laravel, intervention

I'm trying to put a image on a folder than i generate with a timestamp.
This give me the error in the title.

Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException
Can't write image data to path (/Users/me/Sites/test/public/uploads/images/1573905600/title-1.jpg)

This is my code :

```
    $photoPaths = $request->get('photo_paths');
    if (isset($photoPaths)){
        $photos = explode(';', $photoPaths);

        $path = storage_path('tmp/uploads/');
        $newPath = public_path('/uploads/images/').strtotime('12:00:00')."/";

        $arrayPhoto = array();


        foreach($photos as $photo){

            $photoPath = $path . $photo;


            if (File::exists($photoPath)) {

                $newPhotoName = Str::slug($request->get('titre')."-".$i,"-").".jpg";
                $newPhotoFullPath = $newPath . $newPhotoName;

                $photo = Image::make($photoPath);
                // $photo->resize(1400, 1050);
                $photo->resize(null, 1050, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    $constraint->upsize();
                });
                $photo->encode('jpg', 85);

                if(!Storage::disk('public')->has($newPath)){
                    Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory($newPath); //It seems it doesn't work
                }


                $saved = $photo->save($newPhotoFullPath); //Create the Exception



            }


        }

    }
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Where you want to store the files? in public directory or storage directory? what I see weird here is that you use `$newPath = public_path('/uploads/images/')...`, wich will return the fully qualified path to the public directory plus '/uploads/images/', but then you try to create a directory with that path on the storage folder `Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory($newPath);` (By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores the files in `storage/app/public`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this that this folder is already created or not.
then give it permission to write

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /public/upload/images //give permission your choice either it 666 or 775 or 777
```

and

```
$newPath = public_path('/uploads/images/').strtotime('12:00:00')."/";
            if (!file_exists($newPath)) {
                mkdir($newPath, 0755);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this line of code
$newPhotoName = Str::slug($request->get('titre')."-".$i,"-").".jpg";

is it suppose to be 
$newPhotoName = Str::slug($request->get('title')."-".$i,"-").".jpg";

I mean $request->get('title') instead of $request->get('titre').

**OR**

You can check out your input name from blade against your request validation and also your model fillable if they are same.

I hope this helps.